# Can't add strikethrough to ListView item in onCreate

Tags: java, android

I am creating a tasklist app.

I have two arrayLists: taskArray and taskArray2. taskArray contains the tasks: `"milk", "bread"`. taskArray2 contains the states of the tasks: `"true", "false"`. "true" indicates that the corresponding task should have a strikethrough through it, indicating that it is completed. "false" means the opposite. In this example, "milk" should have a strikethrough and "bread" should not.

I also have a ListView tasks, which displays the tasks and the strikethroughs.

For some reason, the below code displays the tasks, but does not display the necessary strikethroughs.

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    public View v;
    public ListView tasks;
    public ArrayList<String> taskArray;
    public ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    public ArrayList<String> taskArray2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tasks = findViewById(R.id.tasks);
        taskArray = FileHelper.readData(this);
        taskArray2 = FileHelper2.readData(this);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, taskArray);
        tasks.setAdapter(adapter);
        tasks.setOnItemClickListener(this);


        }
        for(int i = 0;i<taskArray2.size();i++){
            if (taskArray2.get(i).equals("true")) {
                View v = adapter.getView(i,null,tasks);
                TextView text = (TextView) v;
                text.setPaintFlags(text.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
            }
        }
    }
```

I have done extensive research to try to fix this problem, including using onItemClick, restarting the activity, and using Log.d() to make sure that the for loop is running. However, the aforementioned problem continues to exist. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As previously mentioned, you need a custom `Adapter`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57541211/how-to-add-strikethroughs-through-specific-items-in-a-listview#comment101546732_57541211.

Comment: thanks, i fixed my problem.